# Compiler cache for Scala?

Tags: scala, caching, compiler-construction, build

Compilation in Scala is fairly slow. Are there any hopes to make it faster?

One thing which comes to my mind is Scala equivalent of ccache: a cache where compiler does not have to recompile some parts. I know that type inference make things more complicated, but I wonder whether it is feasible at all. Perhaps caching should be done on different level (e.g. AST) or it needs to do some kind of preprocessing.

I will be happy to see some estimates how much could be potentially saved if that kind of tool exists. What kind of challenges are needed to be solved to build it?

Comment: You didn't specify what you would like to cache. You mention ccache but it's targeting C++ which has vastly different compilation scheme compared to Scala.

I think what you are looking for is incremental compilation. Sbt has this feature implemented but still it's still buggy (can recompile too much).

If the question was clearer like specifying what exactly should be cashed then I might be able to answer more precisely.

Comment: Original ccache works that it caches somewhat preprocessed .c .cpp files to object binaries. From the programmer perspective it is not that important as long as it speed up builds. A few possibilities:
- files itself (not possible because of type inference)
- AST
- some kind of preprocessed files

Comment: sbt caches .class files by recompiling what's really needed. I think that's exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As well as SBT which only recompiles what's needed, [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) helps to solve this problem and has Scala support.

Comment: SBT recompiles a lot that isn't needed, and often fails to recompile what *is* needed.